# React with TypeScript - Authorization and component visibility depending on user claims

Tags: reactjs, react-router, authorization, react-typescript

I am working on a react application.

I am trying to create login and register functionality.

I have a `Authorized.tsx` component which looks like this

```
export const Authorized = (props: authorizedProps) => {
  const [isAuthorized, setIsAuthorized] = useState(true);
  const { claims } = useContext(AuthContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.role) {
      const index = claims.findIndex(
        claim => claim.name === 'role' && claim.value === props.role)
      setIsAuthorized(index > -1);
    } else {
        setIsAuthorized(claims.length > 0);
    }
  }, [claims, props.role]);

  return (
    <>
        {isAuthorized ? props.authorized : props.notAuthorized}
    </>
    );
};

interface authorizedProps {
  authorized: ReactElement;
  notAuthorized?: ReactElement;
  role?: string;
}
```

This component hides and shows diffrent kind of components depending on if the user is authorized or not.

I am using this component to only show the `Login.tsx` component for users that are not logged in. I dont want anyone who is not logged in to be able to visit the website.

In my `Index.tsx` I am using the `Authorized.tsx` component like this

```
const Index = () => {
  const [claims, setClaims] = useState<claim[]>([
    // { name: "email", value: "test@hotmail.com" },
  ]);

  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ claims, update: setClaims }}>
          <Authorized authorized={<App />} notAuthorized={<Login />} />
        </AuthContext.Provider>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
};
```

All the authorized users will be able to visit the site, everyone else will be asked to log in.

However, the problem I have is when I tried adding the `Register.tsx` component into the `Login.tsx` component as a navigational link.

I wish to be able to navigate between `Register` and `Login`

This is how the `Login.tsx` component looks like

```
export const Login = () => {

  return (
    <>
      <h3>Log in</h3>
      <DisplayErrors errors={errors} />
      <AuthForm
        model={{ email: "", password: "" }}
        onSubmit={async (values) => await login(values)}
        BtnText="Log in" />
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/register">
              <Register />
            </Route>
            <Link to='/register'>Register</Link>
          </Switch>
    </>
  );
};
```

But what actually happends when I press the 'Register' link is that the `Register` component gets added below the `Login` component

Before pressing the 'Register' link

[image]

After pressing the 'Register' link

[image]

I understand it has something to do with the `Authorized.tsx` component in `Index.tsx`.
That I am telling it to only show the Login component when not authorized.

But I dont know how I could fix it so I will be able to navigate between the `Login` and the `Register`

All help I could get would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Your link is outside of the `Switch`. Your components should be wrapped by it, otherwise it won't work

Comment: tried this, sadly the same problem

Comment: You are currently adding `Register` inside of `Login`. You have to declare and switch your route in `Index` which is router component

Comment: yeah, this makes sense. But still same problem as before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current implementation you are rendering a `Login` component that then also renders a route for a `Register` component to be rendered on. `Login` remains mounted and rendered the entire time. From what you describe you want to render `Login` and `Register` each on their own route.

Abstract both these components into a parent component that manages the route matching and rendering.

Example

```
const Unauthenticated = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/register" component={Register} />
    <Route component={Login} />
  </Switch>
);
```

...

```
export const Login = () => {
  ...

  return (
    <>
      <h3>Log in</h3>
      <DisplayErrors errors={errors} />
      <AuthForm
        model={{ email: "", password: "" }}
        onSubmit={login}
        BtnText="Log in"
      />
      <Link to='/register'>Register</Link>
    </>
  );
};
```

...

```
const Index = () => {
  const [claims, setClaims] = useState<claim[]>([
    // { name: "email", value: "test@hotmail.com" },
  ]);

  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ claims, update: setClaims }}>
          <Authorized
            authorized={<App />}
            notAuthorized={<Unauthenticated />}
          />
        </AuthContext.Provider>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
};
```